# Plesk Dependencies removed along with PHP removal in CentOS

Tags: php, linux, centos, server, plesk

I was trying to downgrade PHP on my Server with CentOS. Now when I tried uninstall PHP it removed Plesk as well. Now I can't get my server working again after installing everything back, looks like the Plesk dependencies are lost. Is there any other way to get my server running again ? I don't have a backup either.

Comment: Why were you trying to *downgrade* PHP?  Plesk needed the newer version, so when you downgraded, its dependencies were not met so it was uninstalled.  If you want Plesk back, you'll have to upgrade PHP again.  Try to install Plesk again, and you'll see it pull in the versions it needs.

Comment: as some of my website admin were not allowed to login ever-since I upgraded. Those Site were in PHP not it Yii2. I thought the downgrading would be the best option to fix the problem. Upgrading the PHP again will put me back to the problem state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which php version you want to install on your server?

You can install multiple PHP versions in Plesk 12, Please check with following URL an try to install it.

http://kb.odin.com/en/125146

Comment: yeah installing plesk12 , different version did the job. thankx !!